# databricks: check if the mountpoint already mounted

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

How to check if the mount point is already mounted before mount in databricks python ??

```
dbutils.fs.mount
```

Thanks

Comment: Solution to a similar question discussed here: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/8103/graceful-dbutils-mountunmount.html

Answer (score 18):

**Try this:**

```
def sub_unmount(str_path):
    if any(mount.mountPoint == str_path for mount in dbutils.fs.mounts()):
        dbutils.fs.unmount(str_path)

sub_unmount('/mnt/flightdata')
```

**Result:**

/mnt/flightdata has been unmounted.

**Verify with this:**

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/")
```

Inspired by this:
https://forums.databricks.com/questions/8103/graceful-dbutils-mountunmount.html

Comment: thanks for this! Hvae a question, what happens if we don't unmount a path? Lets say a data lake path

Answer (score 6):

Open a new cell in **Databricks** notebook and write the below command:

**`%fs mounts`**
OR
**`display(dbutils.fs.mounts())`**

As an output, you will get mountpoint, path, and the encryption type.

Answer (score 2):

> How to check if the mount point is already mounted before mount in
>   databricks python ??

You can use the below cmdlet to check if the mount point is already mounted before mount in databricks python.

```
%fs ls dbfs:/mnt
```

**Example:** I have two mount points attached to the DBFS and the results as shown as follows.

[image]

**OR**

You can use the below cmdlet to check if the mount point is already mounted before mount in databricks python.

```
dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/')
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking for scala solution

```
val mounts = dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/").filter(_.name.contains("is_mounted_blob"))
println(mounts .size)
```

If the blob is mounted it will give a non zero size.